# Position Two Table TRs Side By Side

Tags: html, css, html-table

Whenever I try to absolutely position a TD inside a TR, the TD's top: and left: CSS properties align it with the page or the table as reference and not its direct parent (TR with position:relative set).

[Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/cbEDJ/). (notice the first TR is at the bottom of the result window due to this issue) I am trying to align the TD with the "Headline" text to take 50% of the row and the "Text" to take up the remaining 50%.

I realize this can be done by moving both elements inside a single TR and placing them in two TDs, but the HTML code is generated server-side in this case, so I am stuck to trying to achieve this via CSS. Basically, modifying the HTML code is not an option.

Comment: Are you using tables for layout? You may not know this but in 2012 this is considered bad practice. Try refactoring your code to use divs and other semantic elements instead.

Comment: can you please give us the server-side code.. maybe this can be done by printing the table as it should.

Comment: Try coding for the semantic web - it's 2012. `<tr>` elements define table rows, i.e. elements within a table that are designed to run under one another. It looks like you're trying to define a layout - a really bad practice with tables. Try using `div` elements and the box model - I think you'll find it a lot easier!

Comment: `table tr:nth-child(1) td{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline`.

I just added `table tr {display:inline}` to your code and its done ;) [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/cbEDJ/1/)

**But really For layouts tables are evil dont use them**
http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html